# SSL and HTTPS Security in Parse Server Android SDK

Tags: android, security, ssl, https, parse-server

The **Parse Server Android SDK Documentation** states under the **Security** section that:

`A final note: It is recommended to setup HTTPS and SSL in your server, to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks, but Parse works fine as well with non-HTTPS connections.`

Does the Parse Android SDK already implement this feature? If not, then how to implement this feature? Is this feature implemented on the app itself or on the server side?

Comment: Hey buddy, i have the same problem, you can find some way to solve it?